# How to format numbers in plotly and avoid conversion to millions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, formatting, plotly

My dataframe looks like below

```
    S2PName-Category    totSale
0   Food                6692735.90
1   Beverages           764768.33
2   Others              127971.91
3   Juice               261923.59
4   Snacks              382461.55
```

While plotting my graph looks like this

[image]

When I hover I get the value as 6.692736M , instead i would like it to be 6692735.90, as given in my df. If possible Rs 66,92,735.90
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tickformat`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-tickformat):

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [go.Bar(x=['Food', 'Beverages', 'Others', 'Juice', 'Snacks'],
               y=[6692735.90, 764768.33, 127971.91, 261923.59, 382461.55],
               name='name',)]

layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(tickformat=".2f"))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

and you get:

[image]